# Container is running beyond physical memory limits

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have a MapReduce Job that process 1.4 Tb of data.
While doing it, I am getting the error as below.

The number of splits is 6444. 
Before starting the job I set the following settings:

```
conf.set("mapreduce.map.memory.mb", "8192");
conf.set("mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb", "8192");
conf.set("mapreduce.map.java.opts.max.heap", "8192");
conf.set("mapreduce.map.java.opts", "-Xmx8192m");
conf.set("mapreduce.reduce.java.opts", "-Xmx8192m");
conf.set("mapreduce.job.heap.memory-mb.ratio", "0.8");
conf.set("mapreduce.task.timeout", "21600000");
```

The error:

```
2018-05-18 00:50:36,595 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1524473936587_2969_m_004719_3: Container [pid=11510,containerID=container_1524473936587_2969_01_004894] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 8.1 GB of 8 GB physical memory used; 8.8 GB of 16.8 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
    Dump of the process-tree for container_1524473936587_2969_01_004894 :
        |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
        |- 11560 11510 11510 11510 (java) 14960 2833 9460879360 2133706 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-cloudera/bin/java
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx8192m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/sdk/7/yarn/nm/usercache/administrator/appcache/application_1524473936587_2969/container_1524473936587_2969_01_004894/tmp
-Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1524473936587_2969/container_1524473936587_2969_01_004894
-Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Dhadoop.root.logfile=syslog org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 10.106.79.75 41869 attempt_1524473936587_2969_m_004719_3 4894 
        |- 11510 11508 11510 11510 (bash) 0 0 11497472 679 /bin/bash -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-cloudera/bin/java
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN  -Xmx8192m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/sdk/7/yarn/nm/usercache/administrator/appcache/application_1524473936587_2969/container_1524473936587_2969_01_004894/tmp
-Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1524473936587_2969/container_1524473936587_2969_01_004894

-Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Dhadoop.root.logfile=syslog org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 10.106.79.75 41869 attempt_1524473936587_2969_m_004719_3 4894 1>/var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1524473936587_2969/container_1524473936587_2969_01_004894/stdout 2>/var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1524473936587_2969/container_1524473936587_2969_01_004894/stderr

Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: How much memory did you allow for any YARN container? Your mapreduce settings are larger than it

Comment: Do you mean `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` ?  It is 64 Gb.

Answer (score 2):

The setting mapreduce.map.memory.mb will set the physical memory size of the container running the mapper (mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb will do the same for the reducer container).

Besure that you adjust the heap value as well. In newer version of YARN/MRv2 the setting mapreduce.job.heap.memory-mb.ratio can be used to have it auto-adjust. The default is .8, so 80% of whatever the container size is will be allocated as the heap. Otherwise, adjust manually using mapreduce.map.java.opts.max.heap and mapreduce.reduce.java.opts.max.heap settings.

BTW, I believe that 1 GB is the default and it is quite low. I recommend reading the below link. It provides a good understanding of YARN and MR memory setting, how they relate, and how to set some baseline settings based on the cluster node size (disk, memory, and cores).

Reference: http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/ERROR-is-running-beyond-physical-memory-limits/td-p/55173

Answer (score 1):

Try to set yarn memory allocation limits:

```
SET yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb=16G;
SET yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb=8G;
```

You may lookup other Yarn settings here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/STXKQY_BDA_SHR/bl1bda_tuneyarn.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try with : set yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb=1000;

Explanation is here :

In spark, spark.driver.memoryOverhead is considered in calculating the total memory required for the driver. By default it is 0.10 of the driver-memory or minimum 384MB. In your case it will be 8GB * 0.1 = 9011MB ~= 9G

YARN allocates memory only in increments/multiples of yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb .

When yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb=4G, it can only allocate container sizes of 4G,8G,12G etc. So if something like 9G is requested it will round up to the next multiple and will allocate 12G of container size for the driver.

When yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb=1G, then container sizes of 8G, 9G, 10G are possible. The nearest rounded up size of 9G will be used in this case.

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Yarn-Container-is-running-beyond-physical-memory-limits-but/m-p/199353#M161393